# How does Google Chrome's Advanced REST client make cross domain POST requests?

Tags: ajax, json, cross-domain, cors

How does Google Chrome's ADVANCED REST CLIENT plugin make cross domain POST requests? I thought maybe something with CORS but I don't see "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in any response. This is a link to the plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/related?hl=en-US

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer**: Extensions are different from normal web pages. They can ask for extra permissions during the course of installation.

(slightly) **Long answer**: The main requirement of plugins/extensions is that they are able to access different domains. They can ask for extra permission during the installation (The user is typically warned that the extension can access data on those domains).

Take a look at the [manifest.json](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-rest-client/source/browse/trunk/RestClientApp/extension/source/manifest.json) file of the extension you are talking about. More specifically:

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>", "cookies", "history"
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty cool! Now I want to build a Chrome extension.  

I guess because Google has some control over the extensions and the user is required to grant permission, the xss is not considered a security risk like it is on websites.