# How does Firefox extension app RESTClient avoid CORS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, google-closure

I am trying to make a simple POST request and I am still unsuccessful.

Headers change from

> Encoding: UTF-8 Http-Method: POST Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

to

> Http-Method: OPTIONS 
>    Content-Type:

I understand that when I try to access my server using Google Closure XhrIo , it causes preflight and fails my POST request.

But [Firefox extension app RESTClient](http://code.google.com/p/restclient/source/browse/extension/chrome/content/restclient.js) and also a similar Chrome app can access using XMLHttpRequest and they don't cause preflight. How and why ?

PS: I am not a JS pro and I fail to understand the intricacies of this code http://code.google.com/p/restclient/source/browse/extension/chrome/content/restclient.js.

Any help appreciated

Eddie.

Comment: [Possible duplicate (with chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127025/how-does-google-chromes-advanced-rest-client-make-cross-domain-post-requests)

Comment: Thanks Thrustmaster. +1 for your answer on the other post. That answers my question and frustration :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this piece of valuable information on [HTML5Rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

CROSS-DOMAIN FROM CHROME EXTENSIONS

Chrome extensions support cross-domain requests in a two different ways:

Include domain in manifest.json - Chrome extensions can make cross-domain requests to any domain *if* the domain is included in the "permissions" section of the manifest.json file:
"permissions": [ "http://*.html5rocks.com"] The server doesn't need to include any additional CORS headers or do any more work in order for the request to succeed.

CORS request - If the domain is not in the manifest.json file, then the Chrome extension makes a standard CORS request. The value of the Origin header is "chrome-extension://[CHROME EXTENSION ID]". This means requests from Chrome extensions are subject to the same CORS rules described in this article.