# Chrome's Advanced REST Client doesn't mind CORS restrictions, how?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cors

I developped a client and a server app. In the server's Web.config, I set the property

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://domain.tld:4031" />
```

And, indeed, when I try connecting with a client installed in a different location, I get rejected. But I do not get rejected when I use Chrome's Advanced REST Client from the very same location! 
In the extensions, the header of the response indicates

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domain.tld:4031
```

So how comes I still get a answer "200 OK", and the data I requested?

**UPDATE**:
I do not think this topic is enough of an answer : [How does Google Chrome's Advanced REST client make cross domain POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127025/how-does-google-chromes-advanced-rest-client-make-cross-domain-post-requests)

My main concern is : how comes is it possible to "ask" for those extra permissions. I believe the client shouldn't be allowed to just decide which permission it receives. I thought it was up to the server only. What if I just "ask" for extra permissions to access your data on your computer? It doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Google Chrome's Advanced REST client make cross domain POST requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127025/how-does-google-chromes-advanced-rest-client-make-cross-domain-post-requests)

Comment: Not really. That doesn't explain how is it possible to "ask" for those extra permissions. I thought it was up to the server only. What if I just "ask" for extra permissions to access your data on your computer? It doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the REST client (or really the browser) is able to bypass the CORS restriction is that it is a client side protection. It isn't the responsibility of the server to provide this protection but it is a feature implemented by most modern browser vendors to protect their users from XSS-hazards.

The following quote from the Wikipedia CORS page sums it up quite good

> "Although some validation and authorization can be performed by the server, it is generally the browser's responsibility to support these headers and respect the restrictions they impose." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#How_CORS_works)

You could of course, like the quote imposes, do some server side validation on your own. The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header however is more of a indication to the browser that is is okay for the browser to allow the specified origins. It's then up to the browser to decide if it want's to honor this header. In previous versions of for example chrome there actually existed a flag to turn off the same origin policy all together.